# VisualSVN server and Access to forbidden

Tags: tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

My source code server has been infected ransomware and when I want connect to the VisualSVN via Tortoise SVN the following message is displayed :

[image: TortoiseSVN message]

VisualSVN runs without any problems and Everything(All users, Repos, Branches, Trunks and and so on) is displayed in the VisualSVN server and I can even create a new Repo But I can not connect to it via Tortoise SVN.
This problem continues even after VisualSVN service restarted.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Server's infected by ransomware? Rebuilt it from scratch and restore a known clean copy of your data. Fix the security and trustworthiness of your server before anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells that the access to the repositories is forbidden. I guess that the virus you caught made modifications to user access rules lists or made them unavailable.

> has been infected ransomware

Repair your server or restore the data from backup. And don't forget to ensure that this will never happen in future.